# Not Sure How To Make A Counter

Tags: python-3.x, project, histogram

I have a python assignment, and I`m stuck on step number 7. How would I solve this step? It involves counting the number of times a certain item appears in a list.

[Link to assignment](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~ckelly/1/teaching/cs110/local_assets/files/project1.html)

Comment: where are you stuck ?

Comment: I am stuck at Step 7 of histogram_cli.py  :(
Please Help me :(

Comment: Pro tips for posting: use a specific title that relates to the specific problem you are having; avoid begging phrases such as "please help me"; explain in the body of the post _exactly_ where you are stuck, rather than saying you are simply stuck; post the code you are having trouble with in the body. You are welcome to edit this question or to ask a much better new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 7. Count how many of each alphabetic character.

Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.

e.g `{"Key1" : "Value 1", 1 : 2, "Key3" : 4, 5 : "Value5"}`

In this case, for counting, we could set up the dictionary to be like this:
`{character : # of times it has shown up}` e.g `{"a" : 7, "b" : 29}`

How would we use a dictionary as a counter? Well, you see, they have this cool feature. If the `Value` of a `Key` is an `int()` or `float()`, you can use it like an int or float!

```
>>> example = {'letter' : 13}
>>> example['letter'] += 10
>>> example['letter'] 
23
>>> example['letter'] *= 1.02
>>> example['letter']
23.46
```

Knowing this, we could iterate through all the letters in a list or paragraph and either add them to the dictionary and set their value to 1 (if they have't been added) OR, if they have been added, just `+= 1` to their value.